# Double quotes breaking jQuery (Very simple)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
    <?

    //SQL SELECT HERE

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $options = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $options .= '<option>Data: ' . $row['data'] .'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    $("#multiSelect").html("<?=$options?>");
```

The above is a PHP query inlined in a javascript function.  It's goal is to populate a multiselect.  The issue is that when $row['data'] contains something with double quotes jQuery doesn't like it and complains.  When I remove the row containing double quotes it works fine.

How can I get around this?  Is this normal behavior of jQuery.

Comment: You should always escape `$row['data']`, and you should probably do it when you store the data.

Comment: Data is ran through mysql_real_escape_string before going into the DB but it is pulled out with it's double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Try to addslashes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Answer (score 1):

It's because your call is being coming out as something like:

```
$("#multiSelect").html(""Hello"");
```

Most programming languages will have problems with that - they assume that the first quote you're adding ends the string you're passing in, and that the next text should be a valid piece of code.

You can get around it by escaping the quotes, removing them, or substituting them to something else:

```
$("#multiSelect").html("<?=addslashes($options)?>");    
$("#multiSelect").html("<?=str_replace('"', '', $options)?>");    
$("#multiSelect").html("<?=str_replace('"', '\'', $options)?>");
```

Depending on what the input text is likely to be.

Answer (score 0):

WHY WHY WHY would you build the options with the code behind and than set it with jQuery? Why can't PHP just set it itself?

You need to escape the quotes with a \

```
"Man it is \"hot\" in here"
```

Comment: because the rest of the application already uses jQuery.  wouldn't want to make it ugly.

Comment: You don't think your take in the question is ugly? :P